# Heroku not running bot. Running bot only when run through cmd

Tags: node.js, heroku, twitter

App is set up in Heroku as worker dyno but only works when I run my .js file on cmd. Its a twitter bot that responds to mentions and when I ran it through cmd, I got two responses from the twitter bot account, one of which being from Heroku which I could tell from the logs but when I stop the cmd line it does nothing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65819964/edit) your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you read about how Heroku Dynos work, you know you’re not getting a free server forever, right?